# BASH: performing a regex replace on a path from find command

Tags: zsh

AIM: to find all JS|TS excluding *.spec.js files in a directory but replace the base path with ./

I have this command

```
find src/app/directives         -name '*.[j|t]s' ! -name '*.spec.js' -exec printf "import \"%s\";\n" {} \;
```

which in said directory prints the marked JS files. However I want to replace the src/app with ./

I've tried playing with [[]] and this command but they don't work.

```
find src/app/components         -name '*.[j|t]s' ! -name '*.spec.js' -exec printf "import \"%s\";\n" ${{}/src
/hi} \;

zsh: bad substitution
```

Comment: You want the glob for `-name` to be `"*.[jt]s"`(the `'|'` isn't matching anything... isn't hurting, but isn't helping).  You do not need `-exec` and you can simpy use `-printf "./%f\n"`

Comment: I find your question confusing: You tag it by _zsh_ and the error message comes from _zsh_, but in the title of the question you say _BASH_.

Comment: The `${{}/src/hi}` is expanded, **before** find gets invoked. You would get the same error if you had written `echo ${{}/src/hi}`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your "AIM", all you really need is:

```bash
find src/app/directives -type f -name "*.[jt]s" ! -name "*.spec.js" -printf "./%f\n"
```

The reason being is the `'|'` in your character-class isn't matching anything, but isn't hurting anything for that matter. Your second `! -name "*.spec.js"` is fine. You don't need `-exec` and can simply use `-printf "./%f\n"` (where `"%f"` provides the filename only for the current file). You simply prepend the `"./"` as part of the `-printf` format-string.

Let me know if I misunderstood your AIM or if you have further questions.

---

**Removing src/app/directives While Preserving Remaining Path**

If you want to preserve the remainder of the path after `src/app/directives` (essentially just replacing it with `'.'`), you can use a short helper-script with the POSIX parameter expansion to trim `src/app/directives` from the front of the string replacing it with `'.'` using `printf` in the helper script. For example the helper could be:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

printf ".%s" "${1#./src/app/directives}"
```

(**note:** the leading `"./"` being removed along with `src/app/directives` is prepended by `find`, the `'.'` added by the `printf` format-string will result in the returned filename being `./rest/of/path/to/filename`)

Call the script whatever you like, `helper.sh` below. Make it executable `chmod +x helper.sh`.

The `find` call would then be:

```bash
find src/app/directives -type f -name "*.[jt]s" ! -name "*.spec.js" -exec path/to/helper.sh '{}' \;
```

Give that a go and let me know if it does what you are needing.

Comment: Hey thanks. Yeah fair point about the |. 

Actually I need to do a replace on src/app/directives to become ./
i.e a file in src/app/directives/test/test.js becomes ./test/test.js

Comment: Oh, so you want to keep trailing directories after `src/app/directives` with whatever additional path components are present. Then a short bash or zsh script using the *parameter expansion with substring replacement* or with `awk` or `sed`. How many files are we talking about? If it's 10,000 or less a short helper-script that just outputs the updated filename is fine, if it's 1,000,000 then you may want to find a way to avoid creating subshells. A short bash script that just does `printf "%s" "${1#src/app/directives}"` will do. (removing the prefix from `$1`)

Comment: The POSIX expansion used is a *parameter expansion with substring removal* instead of *replacement*.